# HTML5 min max validation - firefox

Tags: javascript, html, validation

I would like to use HTML5 min max validation but this code:

```
<input id='quantity' name='quantity' type='number' min='0' max='5' />
```

doesn't works on firefox. So I wrote js script, but this also doesn't works. What's wrong?

```
<input id='quantity' name='quantity' type='number' pattern='[1-9]*' oninput='check();'

<script language='javascript' type='text/javascript'>
function maxLength() {
    var quantity = document.getElementById('quantity');
    if (parseInt(quantity.value) > 5) {
        quantity.setCustomValidity('Alert');
    } else {
        quantity.setCustomValidity('');
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: The HTML code doesn't work because you haven't put the validation inside a form tag. The JavaScript doesnt work because you haven't changed the value into a number, I believe.

Comment: try `q.setCustomValidity('Alert');` instead of `quantity.setCustomValidity('Alert');`

Comment: I edit my code(and my post), but it doesn't works still.

Answer (score 0):

here working code on ff

```
function maxLength() {
    var obj = document.getElementById('quantity');
    var max = obj.getAttribute('max');
    var min = obj.getAttribute('min');
    if (obj.value > max || obj.value < min) {
        obj.setCustomValidity('Alert ');
    } else {
        obj.setCustomValidity('');
    }
}
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/nHSb2/1/)

Answer (score 0):

your code works as is.

[image]

I think you forgot to mention `<!doctype html>` in the start of the doc.

Answer (score 0):

You have to write the HTML Validation inside a form tag

```
<form>
   <input id='quantity' name='quantity' type='number' min='0' max='5' />
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could write an `onkeydown` or an `onkeypress` event that'll check the key being pressed.

```
document.getElementById("quantity").onkeypress = function(e){

   //for browser compatibility
   var keyCode = e.keyCode || e.charCode || e.which;
   if(keyCode<48||keyCode>53)
    {      
          //suppress the key or do whatever else you want with it
          return false;
    }

}
```

I haven't checked this code, so don't take it on faith, but that should help.